# reducing url length in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

i have this form :

```
<h1> Global data management </h1> </br> </br>
<h2>Enter the conditions and click "find" option to search for users based on conditions. </br> Or click the "List" option to list all the data.  </h2>
</br></br></br>
<%= form_for(:find_field, url: find_field_path , method: :get) do |f| %>
<div class="row">
      <div class="span8 offset1">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "span4">
              <div class="field">
              <%= f.label :data_type_choice, "Data type" %> 
              <%= f.select :data_type_choice, [["all","all"],["2D","2D"],["3D","3D"],["2D3C","2D3C"],["3D3C","3D3C"]] , :name => nil%>
              </div>
              </br></br>
              <h3> COMPLETED WITHIN </h3>:</br>
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :from_date_choice , "From date " %>
                <%= f.date_select :from_date_choice , :name => nil%>
              </div>          
            </div>

            <div class = "span4">     
              <div class="field">
              <%= f.label :basin_choice, "Basin" %>
              <%= f.select :basin_choice, [["all","all"],["Cauvery","Cauvery"],["KG-PG","KG-PG"],["others","others"]] , :name => nil %>
              </div>      
              </br></br>
              <h3>&nbsp</h3>
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :to_date_choice , "To date " %>
                <%= f.date_select :to_date_choice , :name => nil %>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>    

                </br></br>
              <%= f.submit "  Search  ", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

      </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

everything works perfectly, all the parameters are passed correctly etc, but in the view where im trying to display the result, i get a HUGE url like so:

```
http://localhost:3000/global/data/find?utf8=%E2%9C%93&find_field%5Bdata_type_choice%5D=2D&find_field%5Bfrom_date_choice%281i%29%5D=2012&find_field%5Bfrom_date_choice%282i%29%5D=7&find_field%5Bfrom_date_choice%283i%29%5D=9&find_field%5Bbasin_choice%5D=KG-PG&find_field%5Bto_date_choice%281i%29%5D=2012&find_field%5Bto_date_choice%282i%29%5D=7&find_field%5Bto_date_choice%283i%29%5D=9&commit=++Search++
```

ive tried using the ":name => nil" as shown in this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form) 
why is this happening and how can i reduce the url size to just "http://localhost:3000/global/data/find" ?

EDIT:

this is my find method in fields_controller:

```
  def find

    @data_type_choice = params[:find_field][:data_type_choice]
    @basin_choice = params[:find_field][:basin_choice]
    @from_date_choice = params[:find_field][:from_date_choice]
    @to_date_choice = params[:find_field][:to_date_choice]

  end
```

i also want to display the data entered in the form through find.html.erb like so:

```
<h1><%= @data_type_choice %> dsfgdfsg</h1>
```

if i make it a post request, the erb is not being rendered! what can i do?

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your method from GET to POST and change the routes accordingly.

Try

```
<%= form_for(:find_field, url: find_field_path , method: :post) do |f| %>
```

Your routing file should match the request as POST.

Comment: i've edited my question, please tell me how i can handle that.

Comment: Does the function 'find' called? or Are you getting template missing error?

Comment: okay, i made it work, somehow just f.submit made it call fields#create :/. but when i removed it and added a : <%= button_to "search", find_field_path %> , everything magically worked! do u know why that happened? n thanks for the help :)